# Send RabbitMQ message on Spring Application shutdown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a monitor service that sends a message to rabbitMQ on application startup, application shutdown and every minute (tick).

The startup and tick events work fine.
When the class was originally written the shutdown event also worked.

I am using spring-boot-starter-amqp 1.3.3.RELEASE

The event was fired on the `destroy` method of the `DisposableBean` interface.

I have also tried implementing `ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>` interface and `Lifecycle` interface

Both the above methods return:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ApplicationContext is closed and
>   the ConnectionFactory can no longer create connections.

I notice there was a bug fix https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-536 wich suggests the `Lifecycle` interface.

How do I ensure my shutdown event message is sent before the RabbitMQ connection is closed?

**EDIT: More info and Latest Code**

The application has multiple connection factories to different servers. The Monitor Service copnnects to the RabbitMQ server via `monitorRabbitTemplate`.

The issue seems to be the  `monitorRabbitTemplate` connection Factory gets the Lifecycle/Shutdown/Dispose event before the `MonitorService`.

Latest code (using `Lifecycle` instead of `ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>`  and `DisposableBean`):

```
@Component
public class MonitorServiceImpl implements  MonitorService , Lifecycle {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MonitorServiceImpl.class);

    private final RabbitTemplate monitorRabbitTemplate;
    private final String queueName;
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Autowired
    public MonitorServiceImpl(@Qualifier("monitorRabbitTemplate") final RabbitTemplate monitorRabbitTemplate,
                              @Value("${monitor.rabbitmq.queue.name:monitor}") final String queueName) {
        this.monitorRabbitTemplate = monitorRabbitTemplate;
        this.queueName = queueName;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000)
    public void tick() {
        try {
            send(new Monitor(Status.INFO, "I am here"));
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("FAILED TO SEND TICK EVENT", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void send(final Monitor monitor) {
        try {
            final Message message = MessageBuilder.withBody(gson.toJson(monitor).getBytes())
                .setContentType("application/json").setPriority(0).setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.PERSISTENT)
                .build();

            monitorRabbitTemplate.send(queueName, message);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("FAILED TO SEND MONITOR EVENT", e);
            LOGGER.error("FAILED TO SEND MONITOR EVENT to {}:{}", monitorRabbitTemplate.getConnectionFactory()
                .getHost(), monitorRabbitTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getPort());

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        try {
            send(new Monitor(Status.STARTING, "Application starting up..."));
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("FAILED TO SEND STARTUP EVENT", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        try {
            send(new Monitor(Status.TERMINATING, "Application shutdown..."));
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("FAILED TO SEND SHUTDOWN EVENT", e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could share some code/build configuration? Because listening to `ContextClosedEvent` and implementing `Lifecycle` both work for me.

Here's my application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringRabbitmqDemoApplication {

    @Component
    public static class Whatever implements Lifecycle {
        private final RabbitTemplate template;

        @Autowired
        public Whatever(RabbitTemplate template) {
            this.template = template;
        }

        @EventListener
        public void event(ContextClosedEvent event) throws Exception {
            sendMessage(event.toString());
        }

        private void sendMessage(String message) {
            template.convertAndSend("", "queue", message);
            System.out.println("Sent event " + message);
        }

        @Override
        public void start() {
            sendMessage("start");
        }

        @Override
        public void stop() {
            sendMessage("stop");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isRunning() {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringRabbitmqDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rabbitmq-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-rabbitmq-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot RabbitMQ</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here's the output I get:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.3.RELEASE)

2016-07-21 17:45:24.984  INFO 77845 --- [           main] c.example.SpringRabbitmqDemoApplication  : Starting SpringRabbitmqDemoApplication on mmilivojevic-hal9000 with PID 77845 (started by mmilivojevic in /Volumes/Macintosh HD/springrabbitmqdemo)
2016-07-21 17:45:24.990  INFO 77845 --- [           main] c.example.SpringRabbitmqDemoApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-07-21 17:45:25.092  INFO 77845 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@27d415d9: startup date [Thu Jul 21 17:45:25 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-07-21 17:45:26.746  INFO 77845 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2cf55fc7] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-07-21 17:45:27.620  INFO 77845 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-07-21 17:45:27.636  INFO 77845 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase -2147482648
2016-07-21 17:45:27.637  INFO 77845 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2016-07-21 17:45:27.661  INFO 77845 --- [           main] c.example.SpringRabbitmqDemoApplication  : Started SpringRabbitmqDemoApplication in 3.456 seconds (JVM running for 4.288)
2016-07-21 17:45:27.662  INFO 77845 --- [       Thread-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@27d415d9: startup date [Thu Jul 21 17:45:25 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-07-21 17:45:27.785  INFO 77845 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: SimpleConnection@7ff53a50 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/]
Sent event org.springframework.context.event.ContextClosedEvent[source=org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@27d415d9: startup date [Thu Jul 21 17:45:25 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy]
2016-07-21 17:45:27.829  INFO 77845 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
2016-07-21 17:45:27.830  INFO 77845 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
Sent event stop
2016-07-21 17:45:27.831  INFO 77845 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase -2147482648
2016-07-21 17:45:27.834  INFO 77845 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```